# Lightning action in managed package

Tags: managed-package, lightning

I am going to create a Lightning action for Lightning Experience to replace Javascript button in Salesforce.
Will I be able to add this in managed package?

Answer (score 3):

@ninja.hk Yes, We can add this in managed package. See below package.xml format for the Lightning quick actions,

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: can you explain me this code ?

Comment: @Raphym This code is for to add quickaction in package.xml

Comment: Hi @thoriyas my problem is described here , it's sound that is it also my problem , could you help me ? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177758/how-to-add-an-action-lightning-component-which-belongs-to-a-managed-package