# How to add an Action lightning component which belongs to a managed package?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, managed-package, lightning-experience

I have a lightning component that I created in my Developer Salesforce Account and I want to export my managed package to an another Salesforce Account.

I sucessed to create my managed package and install it in the other Salesforce Account (with also this component).

But the problem is :
When I am in the other Salesforce Account and I am adding a new Action with the option Lightning Component , it is writting me **Error: No Lightning Component Quick Actions are available for your organization.**

I tried to do it with an unmanaged package in the other Salesforce Account and it is working , so I think that the problem is related to the managed package

Can you help me with this problem
thanks you very much

The code of the component is here:

***DecryptService.cmp***

`<aura:component controller="testspace0001.EncryptionService" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
     <aura:attribute name="listOfValue" type="List" access="global"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" access="global"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfValue}" var="item">
        <p>{!item}</p>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>`

***DecryptServiceController.js***

init: function(cmp) 
   {

```
    var list = [''];
    cmp.set('v.listOfValue', list);


    var action = cmp.get("c.decryptDataLightningVersion");
    action.setParams({
        id : cmp.get("v.recordId")
    });

    var myList = new Array();
    var error;

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) 
    {

        var state = response.getState();
        if (cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") 
        {
            for(var i=0 ; i<response.getReturnValue().length;i++)
            {                   
                if( i==0 && response.getReturnValue()[0][0].startsWith("Error"))
                {
                    myList.push(response.getReturnValue()[0][0]);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    var temp=response.getReturnValue()[i][0];
                    temp+=' : ';
                    temp+=response.getReturnValue()[i][1];
                    myList.push(temp);
                } 
            }                              
        }
        else if (cmp.isValid() && state === "ERROR") 
        {
                error = 'Error , please contact your administrator';
                myList.push(error);
        }
        cmp.set('v.listOfValue', myList);             

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

[image: Add new action]

Comment: did you tried with access with public/Global

Comment: What do you mean ? the class EncryptionService is already Global `global class EncryptionService`  and also the function decryptDataLightningVersion is 
 already a web service `@AuraEnabled
    webservice static List<List<String>> decryptDataLightningVersion(ID id)`

Comment: Access specifier for lightning component..

Comment: @Raphym Did you register your domain in targeted salesforce account ?

Comment: Yes I have a domain , and he is registered

Comment: Ok... I think you have to rebuild the package with quick action. Maybe you did not add the quick action in package.

Comment: I don't want to create an action , the user of salesforce will create a new action and will choose my lightning component from my managed package , he will be able to add an Action by himself on the object of his choice , Of course when he will add this new action he will choose the option Lightning component and he will see my component. Of course in my managed package there are class and other things...

Comment: I had the same issue intermittently the last day or two. Did you by chance update / change the API version between packaging and developing? This error can also occur if there's something not quite right with your cmp - it saves nice, works in dev org but not in package. Packaged cmps seem to be treated more strictly. For example I dont think handlers have an access attribute (`<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" access="global"/>`) so id remove this first and then remove the next part until it works in the package